# How to call constructor of generic type in class constructor

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to create class **Matrix2D** with the following properties:

1. Class should be generic
2. Should be able to accept as many types as possible (ideally all)
3. "Default" constructor should initialize all cells with default type values
4. Correctly handle case, when type doesn't have default constructor (probably default parameter solves this)

How I can do this?
This is my sketch:

```
class Matrix2D<T> : Cloneable, Iterable<T> {
    private val array: Array<Array<T>>
    // Call default T() constructor if it exists
    // Have ability to pass another default value of type
    constructor(rows: Int, columns: Int, default: T = T()) {
        when {
            rows < 1 -> throw MatrixDimensionException("Number of rows should >= 1")
            columns < 1 -> throw MatrixDimensionException("Number of columns should be >= 1")
        }
        array = Array(rows, { Array(columns, { default }) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to check if a class has a default constructor in compile time. I would solve this problem by passing a factory that creates instances of the given type:

```
class Matrix2D<T : Any> : Cloneable, Iterable<T> {
  private val array: Array<Array<Any>>

  constructor(rows: Int, columns: Int, default: T) :
      this(rows, columns, { default })

  constructor(rows: Int, columns: Int, factory: () -> T) {
    when {
      rows < 1 -> throw MatrixDimensionException("Number of rows should >= 1")
      columns < 1 -> throw MatrixDimensionException("Number of columns should be >= 1")
    }
    array = Array(rows) { Array<Any>(columns) { factory() } }
  }
}
```

Please notice that you cannot use an array of type `T` in this case because information about its actual type is erased at runtime. Just use an array of `Any` and cast instances to `T` where necessary.

Comment: This looks like if we use `Any` we don't need second constructor: constructor(rows: Int, columns: Int, test: T) {
        when {
            rows < 1 -> throw MatrixDimensionException("Number of rows should >= 1")
            columns < 1 -> throw MatrixDimensionException("Number of columns should be >= 1")
        }

        array = Array(rows) { Array(columns) { test as Any } }
    }
Isn't it?

Comment: That's just a convenience constructor, which you can remove. It's not related to `Any` actually.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to call default constructor in default parameters.

[Reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) available only in inline functions.